# Is there any way how to get view from `drawableRight` icon in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I need to touch `toolTip` pop-up to drawable icon in EditText

There is my EditText with drawable icon

[image]

I need when user click to question mark toolTip pop-up should be open, like this

[image]

But this current implementation I have done not straight forward approach. I put invisible view on the right side and tracking click on drawable icon and when clicked on icon I set toolTip pop-up on invisible view... So it is not right way as I think.

But I don't know how to get this drawable question mark icon as a view?

What am I doing wrong?

Fill free to ask

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/questionMark"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can have an onClickListener on the ImageView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly, I have already tried this approach, but issue appears when I need to change direction of layout from left-to-right to right-to-left, because I am using two languages in the app English and Hebrew... So if you can to do the same, but with LinnearLayout it is going to be ok

Comment: Try this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html
Basically this is layout mirroring when your change locale to RTL languages.

Answer (score 0):

> as you are using `TextInputLayout` with `EditText` so you have to use https://github.com/ViHtarb/Tooltip  library for tool-tip, and do one more thing add a your Question Mark(?) drawable in right of EditText and apply Below Code for onClick of that drawable:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (editText.getRight() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // Run your tool-tip action from here 
                   Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip.Builder(v)
    .setText("Hello tooltip")
    .show();

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not using custom, I am using this lib https://github.com/ViHtarb/Tooltip , but anyway with lib from your answer, I need to set toolTip in XML, but how to do it with `TextInputLayout` ? because I am using my `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout`...

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution, but still not good enough, because your tooltip will be appear on the middle of the EditText view, because you try to pass `v` , but `v` it is not a drawable icon `question mark`, `v` - in your case is current `EditText`... You can try for yourself to check it. Because of this my question how to get drawable `question mark` icon as a view? I need to pass this view to toolTip builder...

Answer (score 0):

I did some tricked. It is ugly but works for me. You can use one button (as place holder) with 0dp for height and with. Library uses the anchorview for only finding the location of popup. 
See how did I below.

This is the xml

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInput">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_pn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username_pn"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="18"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_close"
                    app:theme="@style/EditText"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the application how to click on drawable button.

```
TextInputEditText button;
    private Button placeholder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pn);
        placeholder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);

        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (button.getRight() - button.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {

                        Tooltip.Builder builder = new Tooltip.Builder(MainActivity.this, placeholder)
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setDismissOnClick(true)
                                .setCornerRadius(20f)
                                .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                                .setText(R.string.tooltip_hello_world);
                        builder.show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: As I told before for @sarthak Gandhi : Not exactly, I have already tried this approach, but issue appears when I need to change direction of layout from left-to-right to right-to-left, because I am using two languages in the app English and Hebrew... So if you can to do the same, but with LinnearLayout it is going to be ok